# How do I reverse a generic For loop

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

How do I reverse and print the loop? I got the first part right but I can't seem to figure out the second part. Which is to reverse and print.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (int j = 10; j >= i; j--) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
                System.out.print("-");
            }          
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This code will print the first part. How do I start from the bottom up (reverse) then print it in the same manner?

Much thanks,

***Edit:***

The code I wrote so far will print this output:

```
*
*-
*-*
*-*-
*-*-*
*-*-*-
*-*-*-*
*-*-*-*-
*-*-*-*-*
*-*-*-*-*-
```

The intended output is to reverse and prints, which is this one.

```
*
*-
*-*
*-*-
*-*-*
*-*-*-
*-*-*-*
*-*-*-*-
*-*-*-*-*
*-*-*-*-*-
*-*-*-*-*
*-*-*-*-
*-*-*-*
*-*-*-
*-*-*
*-*-
*-*
*-
*
```

Comment: What is the intended output? What is the actual output?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: @khelwood I have edited the thread and added the outputs. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on provided results, you need updated first loop and second. Fist loop should start from 9 as you already printed mid line in previous part. And second loop should iterate to counter of fist loop to achieve what you except:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (int j = 10; j >= i; j--) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

So resulted output:

```
*
*-
*-*
*-*-
*-*-*
*-*-*-
*-*-*-*
*-*-*-*-
*-*-*-*-*
*-*-*-*-*-
*-*-*-*-*
*-*-*-*-
*-*-*-*
*-*-*-
*-*-*
*-*-
*-*
*-
*
```

Comment: Thank you. All I needed to do is to add another nested loop (to make another list or second part) but instead change the second For loop in order to do the reverse. It is clear now, I appreciate it